# Incorrect FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS

Tags: android, filepath, android-fileprovider

For some reason my update script doesn't work anymore. It basically downloads an .APK file, compares the version with the installed version and when newer -> updates the old app with the new one.

However, since today the FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Hanenberg/latest-version.apk
```

So my question: what do I need to add to my filepaths.xml to make this work again? I always use the `Hanenberg` folder inside the root on emulator/real device.

filepaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths>
    <files-path path="/" name="external_storage_root" />
    <files-path path="/storage/emulated" name="emulated" />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.myfileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Well you always have the scope to optimize the answer by editing it.

Comment: it's your answer, you optimize it

Comment: Everyone here posting their answer to help people. There is no such thing as my answer your answer if you really wants to help the guy.

Comment: I don't think that is what he means. He means that your answer would be a better answer if you'd explain what it does instead of just copy/pasting the code (even though it works)

Comment: when you post a answer its expected of you also explain the answer

Comment: He deleted his one comment where he said there are few people who post their answer without explaining it.

Comment: I did delete it, because it was a useless comment. Anyway here take this explanation: I downvoted your answer because it's code only with no explanation of what you changed and why. I am not going to improve your answer for you because 1) I don't know how this code works and 2) I don't want you to earn even more rep for almost no effort, expecting others to improve your answer for you

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks. It helped the OP that's what matters to me.